# Kendo Scheduler Change event not firing when programmatically selecting a slot in timelineMonth view

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I manually deselect any selection on Kendo Scheduler in certain views because the time slots already are for 'all day' (timlineWeek, timelineMonth, and month views).

Then I select a time again to trigger the change event.

```
if(currentEvent.isNew() && (scheduler.viewName() == 'month' || scheduler.viewName() == 'timelineWeek' || scheduler.viewName() == 'timelineMonth')){
    scheduler.select(null);
}
//No all day slot in timeline views, so cannot have isAllDay set to true in the select method.
if(scheduler.viewName() != 'timeline' && scheduler.viewName() != 'timelineWeek' && scheduler.viewName() != 'timelineMonth'){
    scheduler.select({start: currentEvent.start, end: currentEvent.end, isAllDay: true});
}
else if(scheduler.viewName() == 'timelineWeek' || scheduler.viewName() == 'timelineMonth'){
    scheduler.select({start: currentEvent.start, end: currentEvent.end});
}
```

However, when in timelineMonth view, the change event does not fire when scheduler.select() is called, even though I deselected any previous selection with scheduler.select(null). This works in month view.

I am thinking it has to do with isAllDay being true in month view, but having to be false in timelineMonth view? The timelines have no all day indicator and break if you try to set that to true... But I really need to the change event to fire on scheduler.select in the timelineMonth view.

How might I get this to behave correctly and fire the change event on scheduler.select() in the timelineMonth view?

Comment: Did you check to see if an exception is thrown?